# Should my Datasource fetch the data that is going to use?

Tags: ios

I have a question,

What is best or the recommended way to follow when I am using a DataSource (for CollectionView or tableView) Should I fetch the data from my DataSource or the ViewController must provide that data to the DataSource?

Is there a right way to do that?

Comment: Putting less code in a view controller is always a good idea.

Comment: I think that neither should be responsible for loading your data. A view controller and data source already have a responsibility. Create a new class (service), that does nothing but loading.

Comment: A data source is an adapter between a controller (or something acting as a controller) and the model.

Comment: Yes of course I have that service class but the datasource must be responsable for ask for the data @CrimsonChris or must be the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Using the MVC pattern (which is preferred in iOS development), I would say that your model should be solely responsible for data retrieval and manipulation.

If you have a model class, that class can be used by multiple controllers, and it's more maintainable in the long run.  Plus it's always good practice to separate your code, thus...MVC

Comment: Ok yes I know that but my questions is if my DataSource should only show the data or also it must ask to another class to fetch the data (to a model, a service, or another class)